# Play 2.3.8 - Why a TimeoutException on Ubuntu 14.04 but not on Mac OS X 10.9.5?

Tags: java, linux, macos, ubuntu, playframework

The controller code below contains a Play WS GET call that works just fine on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) but times out (TimeoutException) when deployed/run on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty). I'm stumped as to why??

```
public class MzXXSimilarity implements MzYYSimilarity {

@Override
public Map<String, List<Double>> yScores(String question,
        List<MzXXDocument> docs) {
    // Output
    final Map<String, List<Double>> scores = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();

    // Map of Score
    final Multimap<String, Promise<MzXXScore>> scoreMap = HashMultimap.create();

    // POST data
    for (MzXXDocument doc : docs) {
        WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url(MzXXConstants.XX_URL);
        holder.setHeader("Authorization", MzXXConstants.XX_APIKEY);
        holder.setTimeout(10000);

        final ObjectNode json = Json.newObject();
        json.put("text_1", doc.getData().get(MzXXFields.XX.getField()));
        json.put("text_2", question);

        // Fetch
        Promise<MzXXScore> jsonPromise = holder.post(json).map(
                new Function<WSResponse, MzXXScore>() {
                    public MzXXScore apply(WSResponse response) {
                        String text = json.get("text_1").asText();
                        JsonNode jsonScore = response.asJson();
                        double score = jsonScore.get("score").asDouble();
                        return new MzXXScore(text, score);
                    }
                }
        );

        // Store
        scoreMap.put(doc.getData().get(MzXXFields.XX_ANSWER.getField()), jsonPromise);
    }

    // Get the Results
    Multimap<String, MzXXScore> results = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Entry<String, Promise<MzXXScore>> scoreEntry : scoreMap.entries()) {
        MzXXScore semScore = scoreEntry.getValue().get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        results.put(scoreEntry.getKey(), semScore);
    }

    // Final Scores
    for (String resultKey : results.keySet()) {
        scores.put(resultKey, new ArrayList<Double>(results.get(resultKey)));
    }
    return scores;
}
```

On OS X Mavericks, this code runs fine in about 1- 2 seconds. On Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following TimeoutException:

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]               [error] application - 

! @6m2a9ldhn - Internal server error, for (POST) [/message] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Futures  timed out after [30 seconds]]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:111) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:169) ~[com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3640) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

The TimeoutException is caused by this for-loop:

```
// Get the Results
    Multimap<String, MzXXScore> results = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Entry<String, Promise<MzXXScore>> scoreEntry : scoreMap.entries()) {
        MzXXScore semScore = scoreEntry.getValue().get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        results.put(scoreEntry.getKey(), semScore);
    }
```

**OS X Mavericks environment:**
Processors: 2, Memory: 8GB
Play version: 2.3.7
Scala version: 2.11 
Java version: java version "1.8.0_25" (Java 8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

**Ubuntu 14.04 environment:**
Processors: 2, Memory: 4GB
Play version: 2.3.8
Scala version: 2.11
Java version: java version "1.8.0_45" (Java 8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

So far I tried the following:

1. run both the ubuntu and mavericks instances in both dev and prod mode but I still get the timeout exception only on ubuntu
2. increase the timeout up to 100 seconds on ubuntu but still get the timeout exception
3. change fork in run := false in build.sbt on ubuntu instance and still get the timeout exception
4. htop shows 290/3829 MB memory usage on the ubuntu machine so RAM doesn't seem to be an issue?
5. No, I'm not using a proxy in either case.
6. Using curl on the command line on the ubuntu machine with the same URL that play WS "gets" works fine so it doesn't look like a network/firewall issue

See build.sbt below:

```
name := """YYHost"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

fork in run := false

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 javaJdbc,
 javaEbean,
 cache,
 javaWs,
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"
)
```

My question is what could possibly cause this discrepancy? Why would this code work on Mavericks and not on Ubuntu?? Thanks for your help